# Gradle - Get the MavenDeployer URL

Tags: maven, gradle, task, gradle-plugin

I am currently trying to get the URL of the Maven Deployer in a task, but it is failing. I am able to get the Maven Deployer itself, but I apparently cannot create an object of type RemoteRepository when calling the method `mavenDeployer.getRepository()`.

Here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///path/to/maven/repo/")
        }
    }
}
```

In my Task :

```
Upload uploadArchives = project.getTasks().withType(Upload.class)
                          .findByName(BasePlugin.UPLOAD_ARCHIVES_TASK_NAME);

for(ArtifactRepository repo : uploadArchives.getRepositories()) {
    if (repo instanceof MavenDeployer) {
        MavenDeployer mavenDeployer = (MavenDeployer) repo;
        System.out.println(repo) //Returns org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.RemoteRepository

        RemoteRepository l = (RemoteRepository) mavenDeployer.getRepository() // Crashes here
    }
}
```

It displays:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myTask'.
> org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/RemoteRepository
```

The stacktrace ends by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.RemoteRepository
```

Apparently, Gradle cannot find the class `org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.RemoteRepository`, even after I imported it successfully. If I comment out the line that creates the class `MavenDeployer`, it works fine.

Is there a way to fix this? If not, is there another way to get the repository URL of the Maven Deployer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build script classloader does not expose RemoteRepository. but you should be able to resolve the information thanks for groovys ducktyping:

```
task printDeployerUrl << {
    tasks.withType(Upload) { uploadTask ->
        for(ArtifactRepository repo : uploadArchives.getRepositories()) {
            if (repo instanceof MavenDeployer) {
                MavenDeployer mavenDeployer = (MavenDeployer) repo;
                System.out.println(repo.repository.url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```